# Determine if numbers are in ascending order using 'all'

Tags: python

I have a list of integers and I need to determine if they are in rising order separated by 1 (3, 4, 5, 6, etc). I came up with the following code:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = 0
for n in numbers[:-1]:
    if numbers[i + 1] == numbers[i] + 1:
        i+=1
if i == 4:
    print "The numbers are in rising order"
```

This works but I was wondering if there's a cleaner/better way to write this kind of statement? I've seen the `all`function on some other related questions but I am unsure how to apply it to this case. Can it be written using `all`?

Comment: I think this would be a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com. There are many ways you could write this test and they would teach you different aspects of Python.

Comment: The highest-voted answer there uses `all()`; replace `>=` with `<=`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It gives an IndexError because it tries to read past the end of the list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this question is asking whether they are increasing in steps of 1...

Comment: @MrE: the solutions there are still easily adapted.

Comment: Thanks for redirect, will read up on it.

Comment: @interjay
I forgot to add [:-1] in for loop,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
all(x == y for x, y in enumerate(numbers, numbers[0]))
```

We start enumerating number values from numbers[0]. E.g. we take the sequence:

```
numbers[0], numbers[0]
numbers[0] + 1, numbers[1]
numbers[0] + 2, numbers[2]
...
```

and we check if all above pairs are equal.

Answer (score 4):

```
all(x+1==y for x,y in zip(numbers,numbers[1:]))
```

is one way to do it

Comment: This'll not work for `2, 4, 6, 8`. Yes, the OP did specify *separated by one* but that's not the proper rising order.

Comment: it will correctly return False ;P

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
all([nums[index] + 1 == nums[index+1] 
    for index in range(len(nums)-1)])
```